# C++ : redefinition of 'class FiguraPlaska'

Tags: c++

i have a problem with my exercise. If I add Trojkat.h it doesnt work. If I comment it, then it works.
I have no idea why it doesn't work. I'm 80% sure that everything is fine and something is buggy... anyway hopes that someone can help me

FiguraPlaska.h

```
    #include <iostream>
class FiguraPlaska {
protected:
 virtual void Wypisz(std::ostream& out) const = 0;
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const FiguraPlaska&
figura);
public:
 virtual double Pole() = 0;
 virtual double Obwod() = 0;
 virtual ~FiguraPlaska(); //DESTRUKTOR
};
```

Trojkat.h

```
    #ifndef TROJKAT_H
#define TROJKAT_H
#include "FiguraPlaska.h"


class Trojkat : public FiguraPlaska {
 double a,b,c;
protected:
 void Wypisz(std::ostream& out) const override;
public:
 Trojkat(double a, double b, double c);
 double GetA() const;
 void SetA(double a);
 double GetB() const;
 void SetB(double b);
 double GetC() const;
 void SetC(double c);
 double Obwod() override;
 double Pole() override;

 ~Trojkat() override;
private:
};
#endif
```

Prostokat.h

```
    #ifndef PROSTOKAT_H
#define PROSTOKAT_H
#include "FiguraPlaska.h"



class Prostokat : public FiguraPlaska{
private:
    double a,b;
protected:
    void Wypisz(std::ostream& out) const override;
public:
    Prostokat(double a, double b);

    double GetA() const;
    void SetA(double a);

    double GetB() const;
    void SetB(double b);

    double Obwod() override;
    double Pole() override;

    ~Prostokat() override;
    };
#endif
```

Comment: Sounds like a typical polibuda exercise :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put similar include blocks in `FiguraPlaska.h` too.

```
#ifndef FIGURA_H
#define FIGURA_H

class FiguraPlaska .... 

#endif
```

Why? Because when you actually compile with your current code, you include the same class twice.

e.g. take a source file that does

```
#include "prostokat.h"
#include "trojkat.h"
```

then after unwinding the includes with your code it looks like this:

```
class FiguraPlaska // because of include from prostokat
class Prostokat    // because prostokat.h
class FiguraPlaska // because of include from trojkat <- BOOM
class Trojkat      // because trojkat.h
```

Comment: what's mean "similar"? Isn't it similar to Prostokat.h include? Or similar to something else?

Comment: @Kawson In `Trojkat.h` and `Prostokat.h` you have added a header guard. You need to add a similar guard in all your header files. `FiguraPlaska.h` is missing it.

Comment: Thank you man, now i got it (i knew something about include same class twice [i read about it] but didnt know that i have to put it in base class too). Thanks !

Comment: @Kawson you might want to take a look at `#pragma once` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once , as it provides a good replacement for cases like yours